# pthread_join void **retval

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to acess the 4th argument of pthread_join. Here is my code:

```
void* threadHandler(void* arg)
{
  printf("arg: %c\n", *(char *) arg);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t threadA;
  pthread_create(&threadA, NULL, threadHandler, "N");

  void *retval;
  pthread_join(threadA, &retval);

  printf("retval: %d\n", *(int *) retval);

  return 0;
}
```

Any idea as to why the last printf causes a segmentation fault error? How do i fix it? (it's my understanding that retval should contain the return value of the threadHandler, so in this case, it should be 0 right?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pthread_exit` takes a pointer-to-void as the return value. You're returning `(void *)0`, which is a null pointer. Then you're dereferencing null pointer, which leads to undefined behaviour (crash in this case).

Comment: Instead of returning an `int`, usually you're expected to `pthread_exit` with a pointer to the result of calculation in your thread, or NULL on error, or something like that.

Comment: First of all, you say the return value of `threadHandler()` but it is not returning anythin which will invoke undefined behavior. Most importantly, you should return a pointer instead and `0` is probably the `NULL` pointer. Then you dereference it invoking in theory UB and ultimately causing a crash.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you understand that `pthread_join()` will pick the return value of the thread callback then you should return from it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *
threadHandler(void *data)
{
    printf("arg: %s\n", (char *) data);
    return (void *) 0;
}

int 
main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    const char *string;
    void *number;

    string = "N";
    if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadHandler, (void *) string) != 0)
        return -1;
    pthread_join(thread, &number);
    printf("%d\n", ((int) (intptr_t) number));
    return 0;
}
```

Note however, that the returned address `0x00` is probably not a valid address — *usually it's the `NULL` pointer `(void *) 0x00`* — so you should only do this as long as youre interested in using the value of the pointer as the integer you want to return.

Dereferencing the pointer is **Undefined Behavior** but, using the value is not.